# Adding collection retrieval methods into the model

Tags: php, model, oop

Hey, 
I'm looking for a bit of advice here, I have a simple model with the usual save, delete and find methods, but wanted to create a getAll method aswell, it feels wrong putting it in the model as its not related to the actual model. Which way should I design this?

My current model looks like this:

```
<?php
class User {

    $id;
    $name;
    $address;

    public function __construct() {
        // do some constructor stuff    
    }

    public function save() {
        // insert into....  
    }

    public function delete() {
        // delete from user where ....
    }

    public function find($id) {
        // select * from user where ...     
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after you have methods for finding, creating and deleting users, there's nothing to worry.
In my opinion, there are two approaches

1) You can use your `find()` method in a special way, in order to get all users (a bit of a hack)

2) You can create a public static method `getAll()` to do the job (I think it should be static, because `getAll()` is not related to a single instance of User object)

Answer (score 1):

Having the `getAll()` method inside the model is actually standard practice. There is nothing inherently detrimental about it.

For example in Zend Framework the [`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Table/Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.html) base class has a built-in `fetchAll()` method. Codeigniter's internal [`ActiveRecord`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) class implements `get()` which behaves similarly. Etc.

A model is a wider concept than [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and the number of methods is not restricted as long  as they handle data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is "model" in your application.
If it's just representation of db table you can add findAll() or getAll() method to your model.
But if it's entity class it shouldn't know about the data source. You should add [service](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) and [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) layers to your application.
If your application is quite small and additional layers will overload it - just use [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern.